# undefined method `each' when creating a new object in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a model using the Rails `generate` command:

```shell
rails generate model Group users:string                                                                                                                                                                          mo@x1[35%]
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20151130131319_create_groups.rb
  create    app/models/group.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/group_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/groups.yml
```

Now in the rails console, when I try to create an object, it gives me an `undefined method` error.

```
2.0.0-p647 :032 >   Google = Group.create(users: "Google")
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "Google":String
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

This is the `.rb` file of `Group`:

```ruby
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your group model have a **has_many** association named **:users**?

It sounds to me like you have a naming conflict between your db column called "users" and the has_many association with your User model, also called "users".

If so, your create() is trying to set up the associated user records with a string, when it is expecting an array of users.

Best workaround here is to rename your database column in your groups table from "users" to something that won't clash.

Comment: By association you mean a relationship to a model named **:users?**  I set up a M:M relationship with a model named **User**.

    rails generate migration create_join_table Group User

Comment: Yes. You have a naming conflict. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the migration file. Maybe there's something wrong with the code block.